# Hiring an arborist for tree work

Tags: tree

I live in Florida and my neighbor has a huge live oak tree. It's beautiful and healthy tree. However, one of the main branch is overextending into my backyard hovering over my sunroom and I want to have it trimmed in case of hurricane damage.

I've decided to hire a tree company to do the work. While the main guy might have proper insurance and worker's comp..I'm worried about the other guys with him. How should I proceed to make sure I'll be protected in case of something goes wrong? Should I request to review each person's insurance and worker's comp coverage? Thanks.

Comment: it's not your problem if his help is uninsured, as long as you're hiring a company (inc/llc).

Comment: The insurance of "his guys" is "his problem". If something happens, he gets sued because you made the deal with him.

Comment: It's also hard to imagine negligence on your part here, which someone suing you would need to prove. Unless the tree is somehow weird, like you hid explosives in it, or the ground next to it is hollowed out by you, it's "god's" tree, so an accident like lighting would be an "act of god".

Comment: Also, just to be sure, you've discussed this with your neighbor, right? "Tree law" is a very bizarre world you do not want to find yourself in.

Comment: You probably can do what you want with part of tree on your land.  Be nice and talk to neighbour letting him/her/them know you want to bring in professionals, instead of hacking away.

Comment: Which came first? The tree or the sun room? I would have considered the position of the sun room first otherwise it should be called a shade room.

Comment: I have talked to my neighbor first. They are OK with it. Thanks for the advises guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**a tree company**

That's the key. When you hire a company, you get insurance information from that company. Ask for it. If they are reputable, they will gladly email it to you to seal the deal. I've done this a number of times. Any employees will be covered under the company's insurance policy.

(May vary outside the US, but you said Florida.)

Comment: I agree. I've dealt with many tree trimming companies in my years with the power company in Florida. You are hiring the company, not the people who work for them. You just need to check them out.